# woocommerce cart system conflicts with SESSSION

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, session-variables

my woocommerce website is facing multilinguo users and I needed to allow visitors to choose their own language.

If chosen, the language setting will then be saved into php session.

```
// LOCALE LANGUAGE
function my_lang(){
    session_start();
    if (isset ($_GET['lang']) ){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
    }
     $lang=$_SESSION['lang'];
    if ($lang == 'en_US'){
        switch_to_locale('en_US');
        $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en_US';
            echo '<style>';
            echo '.zhclass{display:none}';
            echo '.enclass{display:inline}';
            echo '</style>';
    }else{
        switch_to_locale('zh_TW');
        $_SESSION['lang'] = 'zh_TW';
            echo '<style>';
            echo '.enclass{display:none}';
            echo '.zhclass{display:inline}';
            echo '</style>';
    }；
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_lang');
```

However, if i use the above code, though the desired effect is working, when i press "add to card", the website will be put on hold(show loading/spinning) and failed to add to cart instantly.

[image]
I am not sure how the above code is conflicting the works of cart system.

Comment: Your echo outputs you are making there probably cause problems later on, when it comes to setting headers …

Comment: yes thankyou i found that out. should put style in another action and hook to head

Answer (score 0):

The CSS output needs to be do separately in another function/hook to the head.